# How do I activate a conda environment in my .bashrc?

Tags: python, bashrc, anaconda

I use Conda for package management in Python. I have a basic environment which I use almost all of the time, and I want it to be loaded by default when I open a terminal. How do I set up my `.bashrc` to load the environment?

So far, I tried `source activate myenv`, but my understanding is that I need to provide an actual path within the `.bashrc` file. I then tried `source ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/activate`. Although this doesn't throw an error, it also doesn't activate the environment. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It looks like the accepted answers might be out of date. From the [docs](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#440-2017-12-20):

> If your shell is Bash or a Bourne variant, enable conda for the
>   current user with
>
> ```
> $ echo ". /home/<user>/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
> ```
>
> or, for all users, enable conda with
>
> ```
> $ sudo ln -s /home/<user>/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh
> ```
>
> The options above will permanently enable the 'conda' command, but
>   they do NOT put conda's base (root) environment on PATH.  To do so,
>   run
>
> ```
> $ conda activate
> ```
>
> in your terminal, or to put the base environment on PATH permanently,
>   run
>
> ```
> $ echo "conda activate" >> ~/.bashrc
> ```
>
> Previous to conda 4.4, the recommended way to activate conda was to
>   modify PATH in your ~/.bashrc file.  You should manually remove the
>   line that looks like
>
> ```
> export PATH="/home/<user>/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
> ```
>
> ^^^ The above line should NO LONGER be in your ~/.bashrc file! ^^^

Comment: The softlink method is RAD!

Comment: If adding in .bashrc is not working, then try adding it in .profile file.

Comment: Can someone explain what is wrong with the method at the bottom (exporting to PATH)? What are the downsides of doing it this way?

Answer (score 20):

**For bash use:**

```
$ cd YOUR_PATH_ANACONDA/bin
$ ./conda init bash
```

That will automatically edit your `.bashrc`.

**Reload:**

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

**Test (install Spyder):**

```
$ conda install -c anaconda spyder
```

**Run Spyder**

```
$ spyder
```

Comment: It is worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 6):

**Correct Fix**

(works for versions >= 4.6)

`find . -type f -name 'conda'`
check where the conda binary is  and thene cd to it or just give the complete path and run

`conda config --set auto_activate_base true`

To deactivate just do the same but with false. Obviously:

`conda config --set auto_activate_base false`

**Quick & Dirty Fix #1**

Paste the following into your .bashrc, replace  with the obvious and source your .bashrc (`source .bashrc`). Should work for Miniconda3 version >= 4.6

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/<YOUR_USER>/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/<YOUR_USER>/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/<YOUR_USER>/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/<YOUR_USER>/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

*This is a cut and paste from my own .bashrc, you can remove the comments but I find them handy as delimiters.*

**Quick & Dirty Fix #2**

Remove the whole thing with your favourite removal command (`rm -rf ~/miniconda3`), run the install script again and pay attention to the prompt as it will aks you if you want to autostart it.

Whatever rocks your boat :)

Comment: Note you may need to run this first: export PATH="/home/<YOUR_USER>/miniconda3/bin:$PATH" before it'll find the conda binary ;)

Comment: Hi Owl, not necessary, `find` will return the whole path and I mentioned that the user should use that one. And the .bashrc code already indicates the full path. Conda will set the $PATH itself once activated. But thanks for the tip (it's an old answer and I had to check) ;

Comment: ahh yes good point. If for some reason you do need to run the conda binary - say you have a script that does it that's part of some config utility, export the path with the path to the conda binary first.

Answer (score 5):

During the Anaconda install there should be an entry added the .bashrc file like this

```
export PATH="/home/<user>/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

if it is not there, verify the install by running `which conda`, and update .bashrc with the path  up to bin.

This points to the 'conda' executable, and sets up the path to handle conda activate.

Add this line after the export command:

```
source activate <your_environment>
```

from there you can `source ~/.bashrc` to load the environment to the current shell.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
conda init bash
```

That will automatically edit your `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by [@oya163](https://askubuntu.com/users/591529/oya163), if `.bashrc` doesn't work then try copying `~/.bashrc` to `~/.profile`, it resolved my issue. 
Also, run `conda init`, it will setup necessary steps for `conda activate` and setup commands are added into `~/.bashrc` file by `conda init`. Later, one can copy this whole `~/.bashrc` to `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`

I use the below scripts to setup above mentioned things

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
conda_setup() {
      echo "setting up conda..."

      # setting up .profile
      BASHRC_FILE="~/.bashrc"
      PROFILE_FILE="~/.profile"

      if [ ! -f "$PROFILE_FILE" ] 
      then
            conda init
            cp -rf "$BASHRC_FILE" "$PROFILE_FILE"
      fi
      ls -ll "$PROFILE_FILE"

      echo "conda setup done" 
}

conda_setup || echo "some issue in conda setup"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a conda environment to be activated by default when you launch a new bash terminal, you can add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` file:

`export PATH=<PATH_TO_YOUR_CONDA_ENVIRONMENT/bin>:$PATH`

You should replace `<PATH_TO_YOUR_CONDA_ENVIRONMENT/bin>` in the above line with the full path to your conda environment.

In your case, you can add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` file:

`export PATH=~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin:$PATH`

Basically we are adding the `bin` directory of your conda environment as the first entry in your PATH which is essentially what the `activate` convenience script will do. After this, When you open a new bash terminal, the conda environment will be "activated"/"enabled" by default.

Note that you may not see the `(myenv)` prefix to your bash prompt like you would if you did `source activate myenv`. If you want the prefix to your prompt to show up as well, add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` file:

`export PS1="(myenv)"$PS1`

Where `(myenv)` is any custom name you can give that will show up as the prefix to the bash prompt.

Comment: For me this works, but `conda info --envs` still shows the `root` environment as current.  Is there any reason I can't just add `source activate py34` (py34 is my environment name) to my ~/.bashrc?  It seems to work, but is there some reason this wasn't recommended?

Comment: Make sure that the `PATH` variable is pointing to the `bin` folder under the conda environment's folder and not the base/root bin folder. For example: `~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin` and not `~/anaconda3/bin`)
Yes. you can simply add the anaconda bin folder (eg.: `~/anaconda3/bin`) to the system PATH and then `source activate ENV_NAME` in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`. It was not recommended because, the config files (`~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`) are themselves *sourced* and are not *executed* when a new bash terminal is opened.

Answer (score 0):

To activate conda environment simply put this at the end of your *.bashrc* file
to open *.bashrc* open terminal, go to home directory.
Run/type `nano .bashrc`, at the prompt put the following at the end of the file:

```
conda activate my_environment_name
```

now save the *.bashrc* file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>)
press enter.

Comment: While I am  no conda expert, I can tell you `~$` refers to nothing but `~$` (which isn't anything). `~` or `$HOME` will reference `/home/user/`

Comment: yes "~ "is what im referring to.  so when you see ~$ your in home environment just trying to explain so anyone can understand, its pity you downvoted over the dollar sign as this could have been helpful pertaining to the actual question in hand...

Comment: Unfortunately for me, I commented but did not downvote (so now I get the aftermath).. In any event how can anyone understand `~$` as the correct path when it isn't even a path?

Comment: ok point taken , i will try and be more "specific"

Comment: This used to work but longer does -- at least on Mac (for those of us who still use bash rather than Apple's recommended zsh).  The above command at the end of .bashrc is ignored, and conda starts up in "base" environment regardless of which environment you try to activate.

Comment: ^Ooo just found a fix for my previous comment: run `conda config --set auto_activate_base false` to disable the auto loading of base. After that, it WILL start up with the environment you specify!

Answer (score 0):

This may be somewhere above (but I got it wrong first off). Its important that in your bashrc file you first export your conda path. So the path to conda (or miniconda etc) will come above the `conda activate <env>` line. The format is like so:

```
export <path to conda bin>

<any other conda initializations>

conda activate <env>
```